# How do I encode time in high dimensional space?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-engineering, word-embeddings

I have a dataset of form `text, text, category, category, time, text` and I would like to apply the attention mechanism to it. This requires that all inputs be in the same vector space. I am using a particular encoding method (from BERT) for the `text`-type data and I can build a custom trainable embedding for the `category` features. However, I don't have a good way of embedding time data.

Currently, my time feature is normalised on `[0,1]`, and represents when over the time period (one year) the post was created. Naively, I would split this up into `month`, `day of week`, and `time of day` features to do feature engineering, but I don't have a good way to embed this in very high dimensional space (say, 500+ dimensional space).

What's the best option here? I would like to avoid tiling or repeating the same feature set to reach the requisite dimensionality -- is there a better way? I could put a trainable embedding layer on top of those three features, too, but this seems suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a good technique or not, but I saw [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05321) last year that proposes a time2vec, analogous to doc2vec, et al:

S. M. Kazemi et al., “Time2Vec: Learning a Vector Representation of Time,” arXiv:1907.05321 [cs], Jul. 2019.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what information you want to capture :

- If you want to capture the passing of time, encoding your date as days since a reference date might be a good idea.
- If you want to encode the cyclicality of time (months in a year), you can encode your month variables on a circle.